# Flutter Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyUser> above this wrapper widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, dart-null-safety

since I updated my flutter code to null-safety, I am getting the following error on this widget:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/models/user.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/providers/authService.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/screens/wrapper.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<MyUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is what returns on my console:

```
Error: Could not find the correct Provider<MyUser> above this Wrapper Widget

This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice. There are a few common scenarios:
```

This is what my Wrapper widget looks like:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/models/user.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/screens/authenticate.dart';
import 'package:tradie_app/scr/screens/welcomeScreen.dart';

class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<MyUser>(context);
    // return either Home or Authenticate Widget
    if (user == null) {
      return Authenticate();
    } else {
      return WelcomeScreen();
    }
  }
}
```

And this is my MyUser Class:

```
// Create custom User Model to get only the uid
class MyUser {
  final String uid;

  MyUser({required this.uid});
}
```

What should be the new implementation? Thanks

Comment: At first, you need to create 'MyUser' and pass that instance to StreamProvider's 'create' parameter.

Comment: can you give me an example on how that's done?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your provider first instead of using it's value directly.

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return StreamProvider<MyUser?>(
       create : AuthService()
       child: MaterialApp(
          home: Wrapper(),
    ),
  );
 }
}
```

Use create parameter in the `StreamProvider` to pass your stream and subscribe to it using `Provider.of<T>(context)`

Comment: This returns the error:
 The argument type 'AuthService' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<MyUser?>? Function(BuildContext)'

Comment: Also, where should I add the Provider.of<T>(context) code?